# How to free up memory every time, condition is met in loop?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, memory

I am scraping YouTube comments using the following code:

```
i=0
while True:

    load_more_comments=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'main[class="container-xl"] button[id="showMoreBtn"]')
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", load_more_comments)
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", load_more_comments)

    if i % 50 == 0 and i != 0:
        html = driver.page_source
        joblib.dump(html,open(f'html_{i}.pickle','wb'))
        del html
        gc.collect()
        
    print(i,end='\r')
    i+=1
    time.sleep(1)
```

After some time I get "out of memory" error.

`gc.collect()` was supposed to clean up memory, when the specified condition was met, but it does not. Also every time the file is saved, its size is larger than it was previous time.

How to prevent this accumulation and free up memory every time, file is saved?

Comment: `html` is just another name for `driver.page_source`. The `del` unbinds that name, but whatever is referenced by `driver.page_source` still has that reference, which is why it isn't collected. I don't know anything about web scraping, but you'll have to figure out from whatever package you're using how to empty `driver.page_source`.

Comment: Forcing GC with `gc.collect()` is almost always pointless. I can't see anything in your code that has a memory leak, you're possibly hitting some large page that overwhelms the parser